# Split Json array in Python

Tags: python

**I am receiving a json from Shopify Product in this form**

**Is there anyway to seprate each product json so that i can insert it into MongoDB  , because if i insert the whole response it will consider multiple products as single document**.

```
        {
      "products": [
        {
          "id": 510927798304,
          "title": "Adidas ballerina 038889 Comp K W",
          "body_html": "Adidas ballerina 038889 Comp K W Details - External Composition: Leather, Fabric - Sole: Rubber",
          "vendor": "Adidas",
          "product_type": "Shoes - Women - Ballerinas",
          "created_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:26-05:00",
          "handle": "adidas-ballerina-038889-comp-k-w",
          "updated_at": "2018-06-23T09:50:38-04:00",
          "published_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:26-05:00",
          "template_suffix": "",
          "tags": "038889 Comp K W, 100% SYNTHETIC LEATHER, 36 2/3 EUR - 5.5 US, 38 EUR - 6.5 US, Adidas, Ballerinas, Buy2Bee, Made in China, Pink, Shoes, Warehouse_IT, Women, Womens",
          "published_scope": "web",
          "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Product/510927798304",
          "variants": [
            {
              "id": 5885204037664,
              "product_id": 510927798304,
              "title": "Pink / 38 EUR - 6.5 US",
              "price": "38.36",
              "sku": "1405-3951",
              "position": 1,
              "inventory_policy": "deny",
              "compare_at_price": "137.00",
              "fulfillment_service": "manual",
              "inventory_management": "shopify",
              "option1": "Pink",
              "option2": "38 EUR - 6.5 US",
              "option3": null,
              "created_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:26-05:00",
              "updated_at": "2018-09-11T20:52:36-04:00",
              "taxable": true,
              "barcode": "4044425754526",
              "grams": 454,
              "image_id": null,
              "weight": 1,
              "weight_unit": "lb",
              "inventory_item_id": 5879408033824,
              "inventory_quantity": 0,
              "old_inventory_quantity": 0,
              "requires_shipping": true,
              "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/5885204037664"
            },
            {
              "id": 5885204070432,
              "product_id": 510927798304,
              "title": "Pink / 36 2/3 EUR - 5.5 US",
              "price": "38.36",
              "sku": "1405-3952",
              "position": 2,
              "inventory_policy": "deny",
              "compare_at_price": "137.00",
              "fulfillment_service": "manual",
              "inventory_management": "shopify",
              "option1": "Pink",
              "option2": "36 2/3 EUR - 5.5 US",
              "option3": null,
              "created_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:26-05:00",
              "updated_at": "2018-09-11T20:52:36-04:00",
              "taxable": true,
              "barcode": "4044425754502",
              "grams": 454,
              "image_id": null,
              "weight": 1,
              "weight_unit": "lb",
              "inventory_item_id": 5879408066592,
              "inventory_quantity": 0,
              "old_inventory_quantity": 0,
              "requires_shipping": true,
              "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/5885204070432"
            }
          ],
          "options": [
            {
              "id": 743534690336,
              "product_id": 510927798304,
              "name": "Color",
              "position": 1,
              "values": [
                "Pink"
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 743534723104,
              "product_id": 510927798304,
              "name": "Size",
              "position": 2,
              "values": [
                "38 EUR - 6.5 US",
                "36 2/3 EUR - 5.5 US"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "images": [],
          "image": null
        },
        {
          "id": 510927863840,
          "title": "Adidas ballerina 451830 Apollo 2 Sandal W",
          "body_html": "Adidas ballerina 451830 Apollo 2 Sandal W Details - External Composition: Leather - Sole: Rubber",
          "vendor": "Adidas",
          "product_type": "Shoes - Women - Ballerinas",
          "created_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:29-05:00",
          "handle": "adidas-ballerina-451830-apollo-2-sandal-w",
          "updated_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:29-05:00",
          "published_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:29-05:00",
          "template_suffix": null,
          "tags": "100% SYNTHETIC LEATHER, 40 2/3 EUR - 8.5 US, 451830 Apollo 2 Sandal W, Adidas, Ballerinas, Buy2Bee, Gold, Made in China, Shoes, Warehouse_IT, Women, Womens",
          "published_scope": "web",
          "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Product/510927863840",
          "variants": [
            {
              "id": 5885204135968,
              "product_id": 510927863840,
              "title": "Gold / 40 2/3 EUR - 8.5 US",
              "price": "35.84",
              "sku": "1407-3954",
              "position": 1,
              "inventory_policy": "deny",
              "compare_at_price": "128.00",
              "fulfillment_service": "manual",
              "inventory_management": "shopify",
              "option1": "Gold",
              "option2": "40 2/3 EUR - 8.5 US",
              "option3": null,
              "created_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:29-05:00",
              "updated_at": "2018-09-11T20:52:36-04:00",
              "taxable": true,
              "barcode": "4003426908437",
              "grams": 454,
              "image_id": null,
              "weight": 1,
              "weight_unit": "lb",
              "inventory_item_id": 5879408132128,
              "inventory_quantity": 0,
              "old_inventory_quantity": 0,
              "requires_shipping": true,
              "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/5885204135968"
            }
          ],
          "options": [
            {
              "id": 743534821408,
              "product_id": 510927863840,
              "name": "Color",
              "position": 1,
              "values": [
                "Gold"
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 743534854176,
              "product_id": 510927863840,
              "name": "Size",
              "position": 2,
              "values": [
                "40 2/3 EUR - 8.5 US"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "images": [],
          "image": null
        }]}
```

**Separate json for each product should be like this that should be inserted into my MongoDB collection so that i have each document for each product**

```
{
              "id": 510927798304,
              "title": "Adidas ballerina 038889 Comp K W",
              "body_html": "Adidas ballerina 038889 Comp K W Details - External Composition: Leather, Fabric - Sole: Rubber",
              "vendor": "Adidas",
              "product_type": "Shoes - Women - Ballerinas",
              "created_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:26-05:00",
              "handle": "adidas-ballerina-038889-comp-k-w",
              "updated_at": "2018-06-23T09:50:38-04:00",
              "published_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:26-05:00",
              "template_suffix": "",
              "tags": "038889 Comp K W, 100% SYNTHETIC LEATHER, 36 2/3 EUR - 5.5 US, 38 EUR - 6.5 US, Adidas, Ballerinas, Buy2Bee, Made in China, Pink, Shoes, Warehouse_IT, Women, Womens",
              "published_scope": "web",
              "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/Product/510927798304",
              "variants": [
                {
                  "id": 5885204037664,
                  "product_id": 510927798304,
                  "title": "Pink / 38 EUR - 6.5 US",
                  "price": "38.36",
                  "sku": "1405-3951",
                  "position": 1,
                  "inventory_policy": "deny",
                  "compare_at_price": "137.00",
                  "fulfillment_service": "manual",
                  "inventory_management": "shopify",
                  "option1": "Pink",
                  "option2": "38 EUR - 6.5 US",
                  "option3": null,
                  "created_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:26-05:00",
                  "updated_at": "2018-09-11T20:52:36-04:00",
                  "taxable": true,
                  "barcode": "4044425754526",
                  "grams": 454,
                  "image_id": null,
                  "weight": 1,
                  "weight_unit": "lb",
                  "inventory_item_id": 5879408033824,
                  "inventory_quantity": 0,
                  "old_inventory_quantity": 0,
                  "requires_shipping": true,
                  "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/5885204037664"
                },
                {
                  "id": 5885204070432,
                  "product_id": 510927798304,
                  "title": "Pink / 36 2/3 EUR - 5.5 US",
                  "price": "38.36",
                  "sku": "1405-3952",
                  "position": 2,
                  "inventory_policy": "deny",
                  "compare_at_price": "137.00",
                  "fulfillment_service": "manual",
                  "inventory_management": "shopify",
                  "option1": "Pink",
                  "option2": "36 2/3 EUR - 5.5 US",
                  "option3": null,
                  "created_at": "2018-01-04T07:12:26-05:00",
                  "updated_at": "2018-09-11T20:52:36-04:00",
                  "taxable": true,
                  "barcode": "4044425754502",
                  "grams": 454,
                  "image_id": null,
                  "weight": 1,
                  "weight_unit": "lb",
                  "inventory_item_id": 5879408066592,
                  "inventory_quantity": 0,
                  "old_inventory_quantity": 0,
                  "requires_shipping": true,
                  "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/5885204070432"
                }
              ],
              "options": [
                {
                  "id": 743534690336,
                  "product_id": 510927798304,
                  "name": "Color",
                  "position": 1,
                  "values": [
                    "Pink"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "id": 743534723104,
                  "product_id": 510927798304,
                  "name": "Size",
                  "position": 2,
                  "values": [
                    "38 EUR - 6.5 US",
                    "36 2/3 EUR - 5.5 US"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "images": [],
              "image": null
            }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `for product in response['products']: ...`

Comment: Did not try this any soo far because i did not know which python function to use to get this result.

Comment: @alkasm Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

This code separates all the product details in separate json files in a folder of your choice.

```
from json import loads, dump
from os import getcwd


# change the file paths to what you need
path = getcwd() + "\your original json file"  
products = getcwd() + "\ new folder for the seperate product files"


file = open(path, "r")
data = loads(file.read())
i = 0
for procuts in data["products"]:
    with open(products+"\product" + str(i+1) + ".Json", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        dump(data["products"][i], f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        f.close()
    i += 1
```